# PowerShell - how to pass X509Certificate with private key to ScriptBlock?

Tags: powershell, certificate, private-key, invoke-command

for some reason we need to pass certificate with private key to new PowerShell session.
Probably for security reasons, private key is truncated from this certificate.

```
$cert = (New-Object System.Security.Cryptography.X509Certificates.X509Certificate2("D:\cert.pfx"))

$s = New-PSSession
```

I tried to pass certificate with -ArgumentList or -InputObject, result is the same: certificate is passed, but without private key.

```
Invoke-Command -Session $s -ScriptBlock { param($certX) $certX.HasPrivateKey } -ArgumentList $cert

Invoke-Command -Session $s -ScriptBlock { $input.HasPrivateKey } -InputObject $cert
```

Does anyone see any way how to pass full certificate?

Thanks.

Comment: See Structure of Certificate.  It does not contain the private key : https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/X.509